# How can I install platform-specific Ruby dependencies (gems) using bundler?

Tags: ruby, bundler, platform

I need to run my Ruby app on multiple platforms in environments that are disconnected from the Internet, so I am trying to package up the application's dependencies by running

```
bundle install --deployment
```

That works great for the first platform, but on subsequent platforms it sees the gems in vendor/bundle and refuses to reinstall the gems and build any native extensions. So far the best workaround I've found is running

```
bundle install --path <os-arch>
```

But that requires augmenting my Ruby app so that it pulls the correct path for the gem dependencies on each platform. Is there anyway to make this seamless/transparent to the Ruby app?

Comment: Which version of `gem` and `bundler` are you using? There's been work done to try and auto-detect the installed path for these.

Comment: I'm using `ruby-1.9.3-p327`, `gem-1.8.24`, and `bundler-1.2.3`.